# WebMarkupMin - Could not load file or assembly

Tags: html, asp.net, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

I am getting the attached error whenever I attempt to press "Enter" between HTML tags:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'WebMarkupMin.Core, Version=0.9.11.0,Culture=neutral'
```

etc.

I basically started an empty ASP.NET 5 project and created a new html file. Not sure what is going on here.

Comment: Re-install WebEssentials.

Comment: Wow, that did it. Thanks. I feel silly now.